# Como usar conteúdos de um vetor para montar o nome de um arquivo a ser salvo?

Tags: r, array, cursor

Já tentei usar `colnames()`, `names()` e nada funciona.

Os meus dados são algo parecido com (no entanto, tenho 38 mil nomes e 38 mil colunas):

```
nomes <- c("nome105", "outro.nome_26", "qualquerCoisa")
dados <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(25,37,48,6,32,9,10,111,140,60,72,91), ncol=3))
```

O que eu preciso é dos arquivos .txt:

```
write.table(dados[,1], "nome105.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = F, col.names = F)
write.table(dados[,2], "outro.nome_26.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = F, col.names = F)
write.table(dados[,3], "qualquerCoisa.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = F, col.names = F)
```

No enquanto, gostaria de encontrar uma forma de otimizar o serviço, mas não sei como posso obtê-lo. Eu tentei (não funcionou):

```
for(i in 1:ncol(dados)){
   write.table(dados[,i], nomes[i]".txt", sep = "\t", 
               row.names = F, col.names = F)
}
```

Alguém sabe uma solução?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basta você substituir o `nomes[i]".txt"` por `paste0(nomes[i],".txt")`.
O loop vai ficar assim:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(dados)){
  write.table(dados[,i], paste0(nomes[i],".txt"), sep = "\t", 
              row.names = F, col.names = F)
}
```

A função `paste` é usada para concatenar strings e por padrão usa um espaço para juntá-las. Quando uso `paste0` ele concatena sem espaços.